# Is there a way to check successful get request in Postman testing?

Tags: postman

There is a way to check successful post request in Postman tests but is there a way to check successful `GET` request?

We can check if data exists after a `GET` request by

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

tests["DataExist"] = jsonData !== null ;
```

Comment: what's the point of that question as long as you have the answer ? there is no use storing this kind of information here, as users can first check through postman documentation ... can you, please, answer your own question and mark it as resolved so we can get rid of it ? thanks

Comment: I think you haven't understand the question I was asking.
The test I have written checks if there is data or no after a GET Request. I want a test which says just the GET request is successful or no.

Comment: indeed, I'm think there's something that I don't understand ... is your question : " is there a way to check successful get request?"  ?

Comment: Never mind @A.Joly I just found out that I can write a test like this to check if my GET works.
tests["Successful GET request"] = responseCode.code === 200;
You can write that as an answer and I will approve it.
Next time please do understand the question or ask for additional explanation of the question.

Comment: Oups, I'm really sorry, I should have asked for additional explanation. Indeed, when I started postman I found the responseCode information before the responseBody information so I wrongly thought you would already know it (which is, by the way, provided in the form of test snippet in Postman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tests["Successful GET request"] = responseCode.code === 200;

Use this test to see whether the Get request is successful or not. This test doesn't prove that your Get request successfully fetched data for you.

Comment: One liner's are not a very good way of giving answers. Can you please add some explanation around this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
tests['board created']=(responseCode.code === 200);
if(responeCode.Code === 200){
console.log('test succeeded');
```